# Get values from different tables in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, **table1** and **table1_records**

In **table1_records** I keep the general information of a dinner party. *for example*, a dinner would allow **32 persons** and would consist of a **menu**, a **dinner-room**, **staff**, all this information kept in **table1_records**. I can have 100 dinner parties and I would have 100 entries in **table1_records**, one for each dinner.

In **table1** I have information for each user attending his own dinner party. For example, ***dinner1*** (on **table1_records**) which allows **32 persons** will send the invite to each person and therefore add **+32** entries on **table1**. Hence **table1** has a **primary id** in common with **table1_records** to find the designated dinner party and it is used to take part on whether a user will join the dinner or not, if he is going on his own or accompanied by someone, etc. I would want to present this information to the user as to make him able to manage his situation (*click on a button to go*, *check number of attendants*) but to accomplish these I need to extract information from both tables. How could I do this? To be more precise:

**case(TL;DR?):**

> **Table1_records**: ... number_of_attendants (int) ...
>
> **Table1**: ... going (tinyint) ...

I would like to extract both the **going** and **table1_records** in just one sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.*, table1_record.* FROM table1
INNER JOIN table1_records on table1.id = table1_records.table_id
```

Comment: How exactly does it work? I've searched but didn't understand, you are selecting everything from table1, what are you getting?

Comment: `select *` will also select everything from all the tables being joined. I modified my code to do the select explicitly

Comment: I got it! Ty very mych!

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for are 'Joins'

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/join.html

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

and so on ...